# Create WooCommerce Product Category Programmatically

Tags: plugins, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am having trouble creating a `woocommerce` product category programmatically. I plan to automate the creation of product categories based on the creation of a new term in a specified `custom taxonomy`. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is your question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To create a taxonomy term programmatically you can use [`wp_insert_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) function.

```
<?php wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() ); ?>
```

It has 3 params:

> **$term** (int|string) (required) The term to add or update. Default: None
>
> **$taxonomy** (string) (required) The taxonomy to which to add the term.
> Default: None
>
> **$args** (array|string) (optional) Change the values of the inserted term
> Default: None

WooCommerce categories are stored as terms in `product_cat` taxonomy, so if you want to create some new category, you can use this code:

```
wp_insert_term( 'My New Category', 'product_cat', array(
    'description' => 'Description for category', // optional
    'parent' => 0, // optional
    'slug' => 'my-new-category' // optional
) );
```

Comment: Thank you! Was stuck on this for hours. I greatly appreciate the help.